# Using Sqlalchemy to query SQL, it cannot return the latest data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I found a problem: it did not query back the latest 'SamplingTime'. The latest 'SamplingTime' in the query result is "10-16", in the database is "10-18".
How to solve it?

```
sql_query = session.execute("select top 1 SamplingTime from SampleData order by SamplingTime desc")
record = sql_query.fetchall()
print(record)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your query looks correct. Which makes it rather impossible to say what is wrong, if anything. For all we know, the database has changed between the two queries.

Comment: There were no changes to the database when the query was executed,I did it several times, and each time I got the same result. @9769953

Comment: Can you select any date with dates *past* 2021-10-16? For example, with a where query like `WHERE SamplingTime > "2021-10-17 00:00:00"` (exact syntax depending on your database handling of date-time types).

Comment: As you said,it returns [] @9769953

Comment: Sounds like your session is set up to filter out records beforehand, or it uses another table or database. Unfortunately, we can't see how the session is set up, nor do we what tool you are using for the other query, and how that is used.

Comment: Try calling `session.commit()` before executing the query if this is a long-lived session, or the code is running in a loop.